# Would present perfect be better in this context?

Tags: present-perfect

It has been a long time since I   bought a record from your label. The Last one I
bought was the teach me single.

I was wondering if in the first sentence have bought would be better as I am going to buy a new record from this label .So because of this present relevance have bought seems to me better

I dont think it is possible in the second sentence as the last one refers to a particular record bought in the past so past simple seems better in that situation.

Am I right thinking that in both situations?

Comment: *Since I bought* and *since I have bought* mean the same here. I'd use *Since I have bought any records* for many rather than one purchase.